# How can i outputs result between 2 specific characters in dart String

Tags: dart

How can i outputs result between 2 specific characters in dart `String`

**example**

```
    String myVlue = 'helloWorld';
    wanted result is : anything between 'hel' and 'ld'
    so the result is 'loWor'
```

Note : in my case the two specific characters are fixed and Unique

How can i tell dart to do that in best way .

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a regular expression to catch a group from your input:

```dart
void main() {
  String myValue = 'helloWorld';
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'hel(.*)ld');
  String extract = regExp.firstMatch(myValue)![1]!;
  print(extract); // loWor
}
```